# Having trouble with a small example from school

Tags: java

The example is from a course, it's for comparing two objects in java:

```
public class Complex {

    ...

    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Complex) {    // if obj is "Complex" (complex number) 
            Complex c =  (Complex) obj   // No idea
            return (real == c.real) && (imag == c.imag); 
            // I'm guessing real means [this].real
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, my question is: "what does this: `Complex c =  (Complex) obj` actually mean" ?

Also I've worked with python and c++, java is new for me.

Comment: Didn't you ever see typecasting in C++ or Python? That's strange.

Comment: No I haven't and I don't know what that means, care to explain, or provide a link at least ?

Comment: Google with the word `TypeCasting` in Java. You will get hell lot of links.

Comment: As you can see, they first check whether the actual type of `obj` is `Complex` and if so they cast (/interpret) it as a `Complex` instance. Notice though that no new object is allocated/created. Just a new reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comments inline.

```
    public class Complex {

...

public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Complex) {    // you first need to check whetever the obhect passed to the equal method is indeed of type "Complex" because i guess what you want here is to compare two Complex objects.
        Complex c =  (Complex) obj   // If the object is complex then you need to treat it as complex so cast it to Complex type in order to compare the "real" and "imag" values of the object.
        return (real == c.real) && (imag == c.imag); 
        // I'm guessing real means [this].real
        // yes, it does.
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Read more about `type casting` at [here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting)

You can also check `boxing and unboxing` concept.

Hope this helps,
Dan

Comment: Yes, thank you. I sometimes dread asking simple questions on SO because I tend to get a lot of "trolls". Having a detailed and helpful / constructive answer really helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
obj instanceof Complex
```

It means obj may be the instance of Complex or its subclass..

```
Complex c =  (Complex) obj
```

Means you are typecasting it to Complex class object if it is of subclass object

Answer (score 1):

It means casting input `Object` type to `Complex` type, after this line you can use all api from `Complex` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Complex c =  (Complex) obj
```

Typecasting  Complex is class casting the object obj type to Complex type

Could refer this link for [reference for C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447634/A-Beginners-Tutorial-Type-Casting-and-Type-Convers) [reference to Java](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting)

Correct me if 'm wrong

Comment: @Thanga It's wrong.. Here Type casting from subclass of Complex to Complex object... How it could be Subclass casting? There specially mentioned as Complex...

Comment: @Thanga Yup.. what would be the reason for down vote ? may be duplicate , not constructive or poor english or some other.. I just want to know.. so next time will not repeat the same...